# The problem with choosing an appropriate algorithm for distributing values

Tags: php, algorithm

I need help in choosing the right algorithm to calculate the matching. I have a module in which I match tickets with invoices. It is possible to match multiple tickets with multiple invoices.

Input data can be different for several such basic presentations, for all of them it should match in the same way.Here are some examples of the input data and results I should get:

Left side is larger than right side:

```
$tickets = [
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'amount' => '150'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'amount' => '100'
    ]
];

$invoices = [
    [
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'amount' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'amount' => '100'
    ]
];

$result = [
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'issue_amount' => '100.0000',
        'document_amount' => '100.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'issue_amount' => '0.0000',
        'document_amount' => '0.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'issue_amount' => '50.0000',
        'document_amount' => '50.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'issue_amount' => '50.0000',
        'document_amount' => '50.0000'
    ]
];
```

Right side is larger than left side:

```
$tickets = [
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'amount' => '100'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'amount' => '100'
    ]
];

$invoices = [
    [
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'amount' => '150'
    ],
    [
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'amount' => '100'
    ]
];

$result = [
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'issue_amount' => '100.0000',
        'document_amount' => '100.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'issue_amount' => '50.0000',
        'document_amount' => '50.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'issue_amount' => '0.0000',
        'document_amount' => '0.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'issue_amount' => '50.0000',
        'document_amount' => '50.0000'
    ]
];
```

Both side are equal:

```
$tickets = [
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'amount' => '120'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'amount' => '80'
    ]
];

$invoices = [
    [
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'amount' => '80'
    ],
    [
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'amount' => '120'
    ]
];

$result = [
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'issue_amount' => '80.0000',
        'document_amount' => '80.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.1',
        'issue_amount' => '0.0000',
        'document_amount' => '0.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1070',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'issue_amount' => '40.0000',
        'document_amount' => '40.0000'
    ],
    [
        'issue_id' => 'ZAKUPY-1043',
        'document_id' => '12998638134790357761.2',
        'issue_amount' => '80.0000',
        'document_amount' => '80.0000'
    ]
];
```

I tried this way:

```
$ticketsSummary = 0;

foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    $baseTickets[$ticket['issue_id']] = $ticket;
    $ticketsSummary += $ticket['amount'];
}

$invoicesSummary = 0;

foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    $baseInvoices[$invoice['document_id']] = $invoice;
    $invoicesSummary += $invoice['amount'];
}

foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
        if (!isset($invoiceAmountCounter[$invoice['document_id']])) {
            $invoiceAmountCounter[$invoice['document_id']] = 0;
        }

        $invoiceAmountCounter[$invoice['document_id']] =
            $invoiceAmountCounter[$invoice['document_id']] + $ticket['amount'];

        if ($invoiceAmountCounter[$invoice['document_id']] >= $baseInvoices[$invoice['document_id']]['amount']) {
            $ticket['amount'] = $ticket['amount'] - ($invoiceAmountCounter[$invoice['document_id']] -
                    $baseInvoices[$invoice['document_id']]['amount']);
            $ticket['amount'] = $ticket['amount'] < 0 ? 0 : $ticket['amount'];
        }

        $result[] = [
            'issue_id' => $ticket['issue_id'],
            'document_id' => $invoice['document_id'],
            'document_amount' => $ticket['amount'],
            'issue_amount' => $ticket['amount'],
        ];
    }
}
```

But unfortunately the result is different :( I ask you warmly for help in this matter.

Comment: unfortunatly, i could not understand ur question. the reason is, ur examples are to huge. cut short ur sample data and give precise description

Comment: Ok, I try edit examples

Comment: @dhpratik check it now, ohh wait a sec....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long attempts I got what I wanted with the help:

```
$right = $invoices;
$rightColIndex = 0;
$results = [];

foreach ($tickets as $leftPos) {

    $ticketSum = 0;

    while (isset($right[$rightColIndex]) && $leftPos['amount'] > $ticketSum) {

        $rightPos = $right[$rightColIndex];

        $ticketSum += $rightPos['amount'];

        $results[] = [
            'document_id' => $rightPos['document_id'],
            'issue_id' => $leftPos['issue_id'],
            'issue_amount' => $rightPos['amount'],
            'document_amount' => $rightPos['amount'],
        ];

        $rightColIndex++;
    }

    if ($ticketSum > $leftPos['amount']) {


        $rightColIndex--;

        $diffAmount = $ticketSum - $leftPos['amount'];


        $results[count($results) - 1]['document_amount'] = $right[$rightColIndex]['amount'] - $diffAmount;
        $results[count($results) - 1]['issue_amount'] = $right[$rightColIndex]['amount'] - $diffAmount;

        $right[$rightColIndex]['amount'] = $diffAmount;

    }
}
```